Extracting a gauge-invariant variable from a given Wilson line? (NOT Wilson loop)
Let $W[x_i,x_f]$ be the Wilson line as defined here.
Under a local gauge transform $g(x)$, it transforms as
\begin{equation}
W[x_i,x_f] \to g(x_f)W[x_i,x_f]  g^{-1}(x_i)
\end{equation}
which is shown in the above link.
Now, let us look at formula (4.2) in p.558 of "Higgs phenomenon without symmetry breaking order parameter" by Fröhlich, Morchio and Strocchi.
There, the notation $g_{x, x+e_\mu}$ is used for a Wilson line on the lattice, while $h_x$ is a discrete local gauge transform. Then, a "gauge-invariant" variable $l_{\mu, x}$ is defined by
\begin{equation}
g_{x, x+e_\mu} = h_x l_{\mu, x} h^{-1}_{x+e_\mu}
\end{equation}
which is the formula (4.2).
However, I am utterly confused by this definition:

According to the above transformation property for $W[x_i,x_f]$, this $l_{\mu, x}$ is just a "representative" in the gauge equivalence class of $g_{x, x+e_\mu}$ depending obviously on this specific gauge transformation $h$. Why do they claim that $l_{\mu, x}$ is gauge-invariant?

Could anyone please explain for me?
Add : I guess I have asked a too complicated question...? Would anyone be kind enough to help me a bit, for which I would be deeply grateful..
